# Rescaling an image to match parent width with React Native

Tags: react-native

Coming from native Android, I'm having a hard time styling my layout. What I'm trying to achieve is very simple : center a picture with a height of 1/3 of the screen height and that match the screen width. 
I also want to keep the original ratio. 
It's working fine on iOS but not on Android.

This is what I get so far :

```
 'use strict';

 import React,{
 Component,
 View,
 Image,
 Text,
 StyleSheet
 } from 'react-native';

import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';

export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <View style={this.renderLogoContainerStyle()}>
          <Image
            style={this.renderLogo}
            source={require('./img/cat_logo.gif')}
          />
      </View>
    </View>
   );
  }

  renderLogo(){
    return{
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 3,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      resizeMode: 'contain'
    };
  }
  renderLogoContainerStyle(){
    return{
      borderColor:'red',
      borderWidth:4
    };
   }
  }
}
```

And a screenshot of the result on an Android device :

[image]

Any clue why ? Is it a missing feature on Android ?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what the problem is. Looks like you have a box about 1/3 of the overall height. 

Is the problem that it's centered rather than at the top? If so, then try `justifyContent: 'flex-start'` instead of `'center'`

Comment: Hi, the problem is just that the image does not display on an Android device but does on iOS. If I remove 'contain', it works on both.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a bug. I found a couple related issues, though they're not exactly your issue... so you might want to add your voice to the conversation.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5298
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4031

Comment: Thanks ! I'll let them know